# Benefits of HDD vs. SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm thinking of getting a new computer but must decide between a **HDD** or **SSD**.

Some people say HDD is better, others the opposite.

So what are the relative benefits and shortcomings of each? Are there use cases where one is the logical choice over the other?

Comment: http://www.storagereview.com/ssd_vs_hdd This could also answer what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry @NetworkKingPin. I still cannot make up my mind.

Comment: Let me make this harder for you friend, you can also take a NVME SSD :)
But in all seriousness, take the SSD with a HDD on the side, if you have a laptop, you can get a disk drive caddy for the HDD.
I hope i answered your question!

Comment: If it helps anyway in Our Office setups as well as my home setup we load Our OS and Programs we use regularly on the SSD itself and as for HDD we store Documents and Various other files on.  Pro of using the SSD for the OS is very satisfactory. Life of the SSD Varies it could last as long as the hardware does not fail. HDD is the same way ive had HDD's Fail for one year of use on Western Digital Greens. Dont recommend those. As for Blues 5 years and Reds they last quite a while. SDD Have not had any issues and have been running with the same for a while now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have have a better understanding on when I should use an SSD or HDD. However, what happense if I want to process files fast, but have a large storage space.

Comment: To combine speed and storage, you'll have to buy a lot of the biggest SSD and to aggregate them using RAID technology. But it's not cheap at all

Comment: @nex84 - Expensive yes, RAID, not necessarily - 2 tb drives are commonly available, and if you have lots of money to shell out, you can get a 13tb drive (for the low, low price of US$19000) - http://www.extremetech.com/computing/221303-the-worlds-biggest-ssd-has-arrived-at-13tb and Samsung have boasted a 16th SSD drive as well.  This is amusing because the largest SSDs are larger then the largest HDDs

Comment: @davidgo - I agree but honnestly I never saw anywhere that sell that kind of SSD. I mean for the public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDD is cheaper, and might be more durable for multiple overwrites (although that is not really an issue due to wear leveling). SSD is much faster, especially for read. I doubt if HDD will be used for anything other than long term archival 5 years from now.

My recommendation is to used SSD, and if you need a lot of storage and don't want to pay the price for it, also buy an HDD for the additional storage.

Answer (score 0):

A quick synthesis could be :

HDD :

- Pro : bigger size (up to 8-10 TB)
- Pro : Cheaper
- Pro : Long time data guarantee
- Con : Slower

SSD :

- Pro : Very very Quick
- Con : More expensive
- Con : about 5 years lifetime (enough for common use)
- Con : Smaller size (average is 128-512 GB)

In conclusion,

SSD is better for the Operating System, programs, games.

HDD is better for data storage

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your usage case.   If you want the most out of your computer, start with an SSD.  If you need to store lots of stuff, add a hard drive.

An SSD is 4-10 times as fast as a hard drive, and this has a massive impact on the overall speed of the system - Its probably the most cost effective change you can make to a typical workstation to give it a noticeable performance boost.   Its also 10 times as reliable (and, if its in a laptop, won't die if you drop the laptop) - although when an SSD fails, it usually fails without warning.   The disadvantage is that the cost per gig is a LOT higher.

The only real advantages of a hard drive is that it is cheap per gig.   While other people comment about "Long time guarantee", this is incorrect - SSD's carry similar and even longer warranties then hard drives, likewise when they say [hard drives] "might be more durable for multiple overwrites" they are technically correct - hard drives do not have a limited number of read/writes as SSD's do, however unless all you are doing is writing data to a hard drive all the time ( in that case you probably need the speed of the SSD), the limited writes to an SSD are irrelevant because a hard drive will fail soon.

There is also an argument to be made that if you don't use the system often (like less often then every 6 months), then you should get a hard drive as an SSD may start to loose its data.   This makes an SSD less then ideal for long term backups - and indeed, backups are probably not the domain of the SSD bearing in mind the cost per gig.

Comment: Reference about the ssd failing if not in use for 6 months?

Comment: @canadianluke see https://www.maketecheasier.com/can-ssds-lose-data/

Comment: That report says 2 years at 25 degrees c. It's also a year old, I think the technology has improved a lot since then.

Comment: @CanadianLuke - Maybe you should open a new question on it.  The JEDEC graph shows times as low as 28 weeks at 30C and 1 week at 50C  (Lots of alarmist stories tout the 7 days)   The JEDEC report came out in May 2015 so its not that old.   Please also reread my post - I did not say that ssd's WILL fail after 6 months of no use, I gave a guideline as to where SSD  may not be appropriate, advising that after they MAY START to loose there data - something that no other post mentioned - despite it being a shortcoming relative to hard drives as the OP asked.